# Building for Apple’s Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, clang, poco-libraries

Need some guidance on nine build issues on Apple’s Xcode. Using Xcode 12.4, no build issues. Upgraded to Xcode 14.2, nine build issues. I believe that all of the issues are related.

Building with Poco 1.10.1.

Xcode 12.4 (No Poco build problems)
clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)

Xcode 14.2 (nine Poco build issues)
clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)

The nine issues:
BasicEvent.h (one error of the following)
No template named 'AbstractEvent' found on line: 31 (defining the class ‘BasicEvent’)
FIFOBuffer.h (eight errors of the following)
No member named 'notify’ in 'Poco::BasicEvent' found on lines: 421, 422, 431, 523, 458, 525, 528, 530.
All of the eight issue are of this type: readable.notify(this, f);, where the “notify” generates the compiler error.

Looking at the latest version of Poco (1.12.4), header files BasicEvent.h is identical to Poco version 1.10.1, and FIFOBuffer.h had two changes that wouldn’t correct the issues:
1.10.1
if (error && isReadable() && _notify) readable.notify(this, f);
if (error && isWritable() && _notify) writable.notify(this, f);
1.12.4
if (isReadable() && _notify) readable.notify(this, f);
if (isWritable() && _notify) writable.notify(this, f);

I don’t know of this is an issue with the later Clang compiler or is it an issue with Poco. As of now, I really don’t want to use the latest Poco libraries unless I actually have to. I really haven’t dug into the build issues very deeply. Before I did that, I wanted to if see anyone has experienced these issues, and what work-arounds there might be. And by the looks of the issues, I’m not sure building with the latest Poco base would help (but I could be incorrect since I didn’t dig in too deeply).

Comment: The formatting of this question makes it nearly illegible. Can you please look over how this question appears on the site, and edit it to match what you want it to look like.